# Optimizing a search window function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a data frame (df1) of ~1M lat/lon values -- and I have another set of ~100k lat/lon values that I'm trying to check again (lookup_df). If the lat/lon in the df1 falls within the specificity of a lat/lon combination in lookup_df + some specificity, I want to return True, otherwise False.

```
def lat_lon_lookup(lat, lon, lookup_df, specificity = 0.001):

    return(((lookup_df.latitude + specificity) > lat) 
           & ((lookup_df.latitude - specificity) < lat) 
           & ((lookup_df.longitude + specificity) > lon) 
           & ((lookup_df.longitude - specificity) < lon))

df1_df.apply(lambda row: lat_lon_lookup(row.latitude, row.longitude, lookup_df), axis=1)
```

The current function does what I expect, but it performs very slowly because of the apply function.

In R, I could use a mapply function that takes does the vectorized compute. Would appreciate any tips or insights into how I could vectorize this in Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using the fonction on the df straight and not using apply?

Comment: You are doing 1m x 100k =10 billion comparisons. I'm not sure your computer can handle this much data